# Py2exe creates a virus?

Tags: virus, python

So I compiled python code to an .exe file using Py2exe.

When running a virustotal scan, I recieved a detection:

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/90fd487928c8616d9c65e2012a615479492362ca55b65ca9c4aa37ad2494b3da/analysis/

I tried removing py2exe and installing it again, and it gave me a completely different detection:

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/5a320dfee8ee0bfeb852257aa338e106140e9682f46568837b6fdc8e837a66a1/analysis/1475851252/

I have never encountered a so-called bitcoinminer (I don't even know how to use bitcoin) and trojan.pyth so am really confused as to where these detection's are coming from.

I installed py2exe using pip...

My code using a websites API to get some statistics. Nothing more.

EDIT: MY PC is 100% CLEAN!

Comment: yeah - it notices that you compiled Python into an exe, which is a common malware technique. And if you get a single finding on VT, that might not indicate an infection, just a bad signature.

Comment: @schroeder Are you talking about a digital signature?

Comment: @XaolingBao he's probably talking about a virus signature.

Comment: @A.Darwin thanks, I wasn't sure if it was something with that or heuristics "signature," or what.  I was curious because I wasn't sure if the presence of a "Digital signature" i.e., Verisign, would help in protection of malware, but don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

To detect threats AV try to compare the file with known malware. But malware changes a lot and thus it is very common that no exact match to known malware can be found. In this case AV try to detect potential malware by comparing techniques and behavior used in the binary to known malware, i.e. use of specific packers or similar.

Of course such heuristics cannot be 100% accurate. This means it can happen that malware gets marked as clean (false negative) but also that harmless files gets marked as malware (false positive) because they've found to employ techniques seen in malware. Too much false negatives mean that malware gets not blocked by the AV but too much false positives means overblocking, i.e. that harmless files gets blocked as in your case.

Unfortunately a low false positive rate usually goes together with a high false negative rate and vice versa so AV vendors need to find a balance between these two which is acceptable by the users.The exact balance depends on the AV and the specific settings but typically we see a false negative rate of 2..6% (i.e. this malware gets not detected) with only few false positives (i.e. small but still existing overblocking). See [av-comparitives](http://chart.av-comparatives.org/chart1.php) for detailed statistics.

In your case a single AV vendor had some signature or heuristics which probably matched existing python based malware, just because you also use python. This is a typical case of a false positive and there is not much you can do about. Once your product is important enough AV vendors might explicitly white list it in order to avoid tagging it as malware by accident.

Answer (score -2):

This is a false positive because python is popular in the security community and thus attack tools are often converted to exe using this format for Windows. Some AVs are picking up those artifacts as malicious.

The antiviruses that detected it are low quality and so their detection don't really mean much.